# What is the difference of 間 (かん) in 一時間 and 一分間?

Tags: grammar

I was looking for examples of how to use かかる and I came upon the following sentence:

一分間かかりました

but then if I look at the sentence below without 間 what is the difference?

一分かかりました

Now, this brings up the question of what is the difference between 間 in 一時間 and 一分間? In the case of 一時間, the 間 is a counter but in 一分間 it is not a counter though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kanji 間 means some stretch or period of time, so if you add it as a suffix it means "a period of ____". Thus, 一分 means "one minute", and 一分間 means the "space of one minute".

In the case of your phrase, it makes little difference in meaning.

> 一分間かかりました
> It took a period of one minute.
>
> 一分かかりました
> It took one minute.